# How to update entity (add and delete some column) in project symfony without use migration for the dataBase

Tags: mysql, symfony

In the project working on, i need to modify the entity of the project without using migration data base ... have anyone here any idea ?

Comment: Do you mean adding/deleting columns on the table on your database without using migration?

Comment: use php bin/console doctrine:schema:update  --force

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify you entity and execute command php bin/console d:s:u -f 
https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/doctrine.html#creating-the-database-tables-schema

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the entity manually and at the same time I updated the table in the base and it works properly. Previously my fault was that I forgot to delete the notations from the deleted columns for that I was blocked. thank you.